# Gwt multiple entry point and NetBeans 6.7

Tags: java, web-applications, gwt, netbeans6.7

I want to make an homepage with GWT that let the user log in and then I want to redirect the user to another page, that will show a table or something else (the real part of the webapp). This will also be entirely coded with GWT. Now, I'm programming with netbeans 6.7 and I don't know how to manage different entryPoint (the home and the webapp) because it seems that I can have only one entry point at time in a single project... I don't want to split the app in two different projects because the two GWT entryPoints need to access to the same database...
How can I do? Can you tell me some tip, or post a link to a tutorial?? I

Answer (score 0):

GWT4NB does not support multiple entry points in Ant projects.

Your alternatives are:

- Maven with Codehaus GWT plugin projects support multiple entry points. Limited Maven support is in GWT4NB since 2.6.7 (https://gwt4nb.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=7081&expandFolder=7081&folderID=0)
- create 2 web projects/wars and configure the DB connection using Java EE patterns
- write the login dialog as a GWT dialog

Comment: Thank you, I think that the best solution is to write the login dialog as a GWT dialog.

Comment: FYI: GWT4NB 2.6.15 support multiple modules in one project